# Selenium Webdriver on IE

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I got a problem while my web app is running that is IE webdriver does not read my input text in textbox element. It still show the warning message “Please enter username”
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? ^^

Comment: can you add code snippet?